# Use of Bernoulli equation $x^2y' +2xy=y^3$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here, I have $$x^2y'+2xy=y^3$$
I should apply the Bernoulli equation, so I mark $$z=\frac{1}{y^2}$$ $$z' = -\frac{2y'}{y^3}$$
$$-\frac{z'}{2} = \frac{y'}{y^3}$$

Now I just substitute $z$ and I get $$-\frac{x^2z'}{2}+2xz=1$$

How I should proceed from here? I am not recognize any pattern

Comment: Now you have a first order linear differential equation. There even exists a solution formula for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that step you can write your equation in the form $$\frac{dz}{dx}+Pz=Q$$ where $P$ and $Q$ depend on $x$...

You get $$\frac{dz}{dx}-\frac{4}{x}z=-2x^{-2}$$

Your $P=-\frac{4}{x}$, 
$Q=-2x^{-2}$

Now, $$ze^{\int-\frac{4}{x}dx}=\int{e^{\int-\frac{4}{x}dx}(-2x^{-2})dx}$$

So that $$zx^{-4}=-2\int{x^{-6}dx}$$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2y\prime +2xy=y^3$$
Rewrite the DE as:
$$(x^2y)'=y^3$$
$$\dfrac {d(x^2y)}{(x^2y)^3}=\dfrac {dx}{x^6}$$
Integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Your last equation in $z$ is

$$x^2z'-4xz=-2$$
without RHS,

$$\frac{z'}{z}=\frac{4x}{x^2}=\frac 4x$$
then
$$\ln(\frac{z}{\lambda})=\ln(x^4)$$
and

$$z=\lambda.x^4$$
let us look for a particular solution as$$z_p=\lambda(x)x^4$$
with

$$\lambda'x^6=-2$$
thus
$$\lambda=\frac{-2}{5x^5}$$
therefore
$$z=\lambda.x^4-\frac{2}{5x}$$
finally

$$\Large{y=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\lambda.x^4-\frac{2}{5x}}}}$$
where $\lambda\in \Bbb R$.